# Mongo: Array field has no values in given array?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to write up a mongo query that finds all entries where the "steps" field has no values within an array argument.

So for example, given two entries with values:

```
Entry1:
  steps: [3, 4]

Entry2:
  steps: [3, 5]
```

The query should return entry1, but not entry 2, for input array [4, 8, 10]. I'm quite new to mongo - any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Post your query and some sample document. It's better to understand and give suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you have some records:

> db.foo.find()
>       { "_id" : 1, "steps" : [ 3, 4 ] }
>       { "_id" : 2, "steps" : [ 3, 5 ] }

Then you would query:

```
> db.foo.find({steps:{$in:[4,8,10]}})
{ "_id" : 1, "steps" : [ 3, 4 ] }
```

the $in clause will pick records in which any stored element matches any of terms in the array supplied in the query